# The align attribute on the div element is obsolete. Use CSS instead

Tags: css

I'm trying to center align div element with this:

```
<div class="container" align="center">
```

But I'm getting error on w3cvalidator as the align attribute is obsolete. So, I use CSS instead:

```
<div class="container" style="text-align:center">
```

The problem is when I use the above code, the div move the left-hand side instead of center.

How can I fix this?

Comment: margin:auto; should put the image in center

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, `align` is obsolete.
Use it like this:

`<div class="container" style="display: block; margin: auto;">`